# Flutter GestureDetector's onTapUp is not always called

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I'm using `GestureDetector` like:

```
    GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) => store.startRecording(),
      onTapUp: (_) => store.stopRecording(),
      child: ...
```

However, I've noticed that `onTapUp` won't be called sometimes (e.g. when I'm dragging my finger and releasing afterward).
What's the callback that will be called always when my finger is released?

Comment: tried `onTapCancel`? the docs say: *"The pointer that previously triggered onTapDown will not end up causing a tap.

This is called after onTapDown, and instead of onTapUp and onTap, if the tap gesture did not win."*

Comment: @pskink thanks! `onTapCancel` seems to work for edge cases, I still need to keep `onTapUp` to handle all situations.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @pskink my solution looks like:

```
GestureDetector(
   onTapDown: (_) => store.startRecording(),
   onTapUp: (_) => store.stopRecording(),
   onTapCancel: () => store.stopRecording(),
```

`onTapCanncel` will handle situation when user is dragging his finger and releasing.

Comment: somebody is using a mac lol

Comment: But this way the `store.stopRecording()` scenario is called even if user is just swiping through the button, eg even slight finger movement will cause that. Did you ever encounter this problem, or maybe found a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Listener` instead of `GestureDetector` for this, like below

```
Listener(
    onPointerDown: (details) {
      setState(() {
        ///TODO
      });
    },
    onPointerUp: (details) {
      setState(() {
       ///TODO
      });
    },
    child: ...
  ),
```

This will solve your problem :)

Comment: This way work for me when the widget have multi GestureDector inside, thank you